# IE Javascript Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have this function that works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but for some reason it does not work at all in IE.

The error message is **'Unable to get property 'title' of undefined or null reference'**

I believe it is not registering the result, but do not know why this is the issue just for IE.

```
function create_the_list_item(r){
            var title = $('<h3 />',{'class':'title'}).html('<span class="icon-location location">'+r.title+(r.miles?(' <span style="font-size:75%">('+r.miles+' miles away)</span> '):'' )+' </span>')
            var add = $('<div />',{'class':'address left'}).html(
                '<p>'+(r.address_line_1+'<br/> ' ) + 
                (r.address_line_2?(r.address_line_2+'<br/> '):'' ) +
                (r.county?(r.county + '<br/> '):'') +
                (r.country?r.country + '<br/> ' :'') +
                (r.post_code?r.post_code :'')+'</p>'
            );
            var website = $('<div />',{'class':'right'}).html(
                (r.website?('<a href="http://'+r.website.replace('http://','')+'" target="_blank">Visit Website</a><br/><br/>' ):'')+
                (r.website?(r.telephone_number ):'')
            )
            return ($('<div />',{'class': 'the_shop_list clearfix'})
                .data('longitude',r.longitude)
                .data('latitude',r.latitude)
                .data('title',r.title)
                .data('tel',r.telephone_number)
                .data('website',r.website)
                .append(title).append(add).append(website)
                )
        }
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Does IE produce an error? If so, what's the error?

Comment: What do you mean "It does not work"? Describe the behavior you want and the one you expect. Any error in console? Which IE Version?

Comment: The error message is 'Unable to get property 'title' of undefined or null reference'

Comment: Still we din't get the version :)

Comment: Well what are you passing in as `r`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that your `r` object may be empty so trace back your code and `console.log()` to see what is going on.

if you try:

```
function create_the_list_item(r){
   console.log(r)
   var title = $('<h3 />',{'class':'title'}).html('<span class="icon-location location">'+r.title+(r.miles?(' <span style="font-size:75%">('+r.miles+' miles away)</span> '):'' )+' </span>')
 ......
}
```

It will say something like undefined or null:

So it's probably the way you have passed the object or any keyword clashes or something of that nature.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've given us to go on, the error *'Unable to get property 'title' of undefined or null reference'* probably refers to the object you're trying to pass 'r'. The first reference to 'r' is r.title when setting your 'title' variable.

'r' is not being defined or created or passed to *create_the_list_item* as you are expecting it to be.

They way you're using it r should look like:

```
r = { title : 'my title', 
      county: 'my county'}
```